# C - Why put a struct inside a union?

Tags: c, struct, unions

For example, this code is from firmware of a USB device:

```
typedef union HID_CONTROLS_TYPEDEF
{
    struct
    {
         BYTE B1:1;     //buttons
         BYTE B2:1;
         BYTE B3:1;
         BYTE B4:1;
         BYTE B5:1;
         BYTE B6:1;
         BYTE Bpad:2;  //filler
    } buttons;
} HID_CONTROLS;
```

Why is the struct inside the union, what effect will this have? Won't it work as just a struct?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you're right, it' superfluous.

However, at some time in the past, the union may have also carried an eight-bit char for easy mapping.

Or maybe they think it may in the future.

That'd be my guess and I stress that, it's only a guess. However, it's only the reason behind it that's a guess, and a fairly well educated one at that.

The superfluosness (?) of the `struct` is a given, not guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

It means the same if the struct is taken outside the union. The only thing I can think of is that it forces the code to include `buttons`. For instance you write:

```
controls.buttons.B1 = ...;
```

rather than

```
controls.B1 = ...;
```

So perhaps the author feels this is self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.  I'm guessing that the union was originally written in case the data neeeded to be adressed as a whole byte, hence the filler to pad it out to 8 bits.  It's not uncommon in low-level embedded.

It was found unnecessary to access the whole byte, but the union was just left in because there was no reason to take it out.

Code inertia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should, unless I'm missing something. I see two possible reasons for this code: One is in the past, another in the future ;-).

There may once have been an int as alternative to the struct in the union; or there may be plans to add one in the future. Both would make wrapping a union around it sensible because the prospective or past change did not make user code changes necessary.